# Is there a difference between installing mod_python via httpd.conf and conf.d in apache?

Tags: mod-python, apache

I am working with a hosting provider who has installed mod_python for me.  I followed the install instructions locally and included it in httpd.conf but they have opted to put it in conf.d/python.conf.

Is there any difference/benefit to doing it either way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, all the files are parsed at run time, you can include as many as you want. They've just opted to seperate out the configuration for easier management.